# NextSibling.Innertext error "Object doesn't support this property"

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Goal: I'm trying to extract the Bid prices for 200 securities from a website.

Problem: I'm trying to pull the Innertexts of the td tag where the price is located.

[image]

The idea is to loop through the HTML document for all TH tags, once it finds "Bid", extract the innertext of the next line of code.

VBA error

> "Object doesn't support this property"

My code is for extracting one security. I did not include the bigger loop for all 200 securities.

```
Set objHTML = objIE.document

Set Mytext = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("Th")

For Each Node In Mytext

    If Node.innertext = "Bid" Then
        BidPrice = Node.NextSibling.innertext
        Cells(a, 2) = BidPrice
        Exit For
    End If

Next Node
```

Comment: I tried to look at the local window when I changed the below code

BidPrice= Node.NextSibling.Innertext    to
BidPrice= Node.NextSibling

In my local window, BidPrice is  "[object text]" as Variant/String.
I was expecting to extract the 8.725 bid price from within the td tags, do you guys know what went wrong?

Comment: Either a link to the website, or a well formed document that demonstrates the problem when your code is run against it, would be useful in obtaining help with your code.

Comment: ^^ Please provide url or html

Comment: Try to print `node.ParentNode.innerText`. If the desired value you are after is there then try using `node.ParentNode.LastChild.innerText` or `node.ParentNode.querySelector("td").innerText` instead of the first one. Btw, do you think you have provided enough information to get an answer?

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the feedback, I will definitely respond ASAP after work

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each Node In elementOne 

If Node.innerText = "Bid" Then 

Cells(a, 2) = Node.ParentNode.querySelector("td").innerText 
'This pulls the Bid Price 8.745
```

Again, thank you all for helping, especially SIM!

p.s. I will learn to format properly going forward, for now, I'd like to just urgently express my gratitude.